# Use url for build context and another url for dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to add a service in my compose file by referencing the repo URL for the context.
So far I've managed to add services that way but I have troubles for a specific service whose Dockerfile is in another git repository.

Here is an exemple of what I'm trying to do :

```
my_service:
  build:
    context: https://some.repo.url.com/repo1.git#dev
    dockerfile: https://some.repo.url.com/repo2/path/to/Dockerfile
```

Is it possible ? I've seen `additional_contexts`but these are name and require the Dockerfile to be aware of them...

I've tried using the url but I get an error during build :

```
unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /tmp/docker-build-git2751315438/https:: no such file or directory
```